# My Datagrid on PageIndexChanging and on Sorting disappears on me?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, datagrid, page-index-changed

So I have a Search Page where a user search's for a supplier. All well and done. Now because I am using an entity framework I do not have a dataset bound to the grid. Instead I have these two babies.

```
  Protected Sub dgdResults_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles dgdResults.PageIndexChanging
        If Page.IsPostBack Then
            'Do something
            dgdResults.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
            dgdResults.DataSource = dt
            dgdResults.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub dgdResults_Sorting(sender As [Object], e As GridViewSortEventArgs)
        If Page.IsPostBack Then
            ViewState("sortExpr") = e.SortExpression
            dgdResults.DataSource = dt
            dgdResults.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

and these two babies are linked to

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dgdResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" Width="1900px"
                    GridLines="None" CssClass="grid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeaderBlue" RowStyle-CssClass="gridRowResult" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridAltRowResult"
                    AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="dgdResults_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="dgdResults_Sorting">
                    <Columns>
```

Now saying that when ever I click on a different page or I click on a column header to sort. The entire datagrid disappears. At first I thought it was because my panel was set to visible=false but the panel headers still remain when sorting is triggered or page indexing is triggered its just the datagrid disappears. no errors no nothing? Anyone had an experience with this before? Any fixes? I debugged it thru and thru cannot see any errors.

Comment: Are you reloading your data into the dt variable (which I assume is a DataTable) on each postback? If not dt is probably null and as the grid has no data to display it will disappear.

Comment: Agree with @Calvedos. Add a debug point there and see whether dt variable has data in it. And, there's no point in using "If Page.IsPostBack Then" in these events as it'll be true all the time. And, I'm curious to know what's in your Page load event?

Comment: my dt was empty. I assumed it maintained it.